# How to use static variable as value for named-native-query inside JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to use static variable as a query for a named-native-query inside JPA (persistence.xml) file.

I'm using Spring boot 2.1.9 and hibernate 5.3.12.

I have an interface :

```java
public interface SqlQueryFacture {
    String MEMOIRES_TABLE_BY_FACTURE = "SELECT ......";
}
```

and I want to use `MEMOIRES_TABLE_BY_FACTURE` as value in persistence.xml file like this

```xml
<entity-mappings version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_2.xsd">

    <entity class="fr.pp.entities.factures.Facture">
        <named-native-query name="Facture.getMemoiresTableByFactureId" result-set-mapping="MemoireTableRowDtoMapping">
            <query>SqlQueryFacture.MEMOIRES_TABLE_BY_FACTURE</query>
        </named-native-query>
    </entity>

</entity-mappings>
```

Can I do that without use `@NamedNativeQuery` inside the entity class ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are trying for dynamic queries through JPA. Unfortunately, JPA doesn't provide support for dynamic queries.

You can't do in JPA (persistence.xml) :

```
<query>SqlQueryFacture.MEMOIRES_TABLE_BY_FACTURE</query>
```

For example :

```
<!-- Query takes HQL (Hibernate Query Language) directly -->
<query>SELECT p from Product p</query>
```

This is allowed.